# Rails3.0.0Beta4 setting session store to database

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-3

I am porting a Rails 2.3.8 app to Rails 3.0.0Beta4.  I can't get the session to be written to the database instead of cookies.

I do the following in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.session_store(:active_record_store)
```

The session store is set correctly - I verify that by dumping `config` after the set.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you haven't done it yet, you need to run "rake db:sessions:create" to
have the necesary table created on the DB.

Answer (score 2):

rails generate session_migration

Answer (score 1):

instead of changing environment.rb or development.rb,

insert into

```
config/initializers/session_store.rb
```

statement

```
Your_app::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

then

```
rake db:sessions:create
rake db:migrate
```

voila!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have raked, put this into your environment.rb not development.rb

config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store

Slotishtype